# Google Marketplace - Installing application and access tokens

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-apps, google-apps-marketplace

Trying to test installation process for my marketplace application. Google documentation says that I can test installation process by using Test Install Flow button in the console. When I click on that button, I see the authorization dialog and I click accept. The dialog is closed and app is installed on the domain I am testing.

Question:  Should I be getting and storing a `refresh_token` at some point in this installation process?

There is an [Install URL that I can specify in Drive SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22329284/google-drive-sdk-drive-integration-install-url) but I can't find documentation about when Google posts to this install URL and what gets posted.

[image]

Comment: To confirm you are trying to build a Drive app (ie integrated into the Drive UI) that is installed at the domain level?

Comment: Correct, I am trying to develop a Drive app that is integrated in Drive UI.  I would like it to be installable by an admin for a domain or just a single user.

Comment: There is an Integrate with Google button that is meant for admins. So does the Install button meant to work for individual accounts only?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a project which shows you how to do just that:

Checkout the section called: Cached Credentials

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/488185/Working-with-Google-Drive-in-WPF

Excerpt from the above URL:

Provided the user allows access, the authorization server will return the authorization code. It can be sent back either by the Google server calling a web service endpoint opened by your application or in the title of the page sent back to the browser. Because of the challenges of spooling up a web server, opening a connection through any possible firewall(s), etc... it is much easier for installed applications to simply scrape the authorization code from the title of the resulting web page. That is the technique used in the sample project. If successful, the title will be set to Success code=xxxxxxxxx where the xxxx's are replaced by a unique authorization code.

The authorization code only gets you invited to the party. You can't do anything with that code as far as API access. The Authorization Code must be exchanged for a short-lived access code and a long-term refresh code. In the Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2 library is a class called NativeApplicationClient. This is the wrapper for the authorization server and it has a method called 'ProcessUserAuthorization'. This method takes the authorization code we retrieved after the user authorized the application's access and turns it into the access token and the refresh token. The access token is what we actually need for the task at hand and it is maintained in the NativeApplicationClient. It gets passed with all subsequent API calls. The nice thing about the NativeApplicationClient is that it knows how to verify the access token and how old the token is. If the token has expired, the client will use the refresh token to get a new access token. That takes the burden off of us to manage token lifetimes.

Comment: Hi James, thank you for the article. My question is about installing application to user's Google Drive. When a user finds my app via Google Marketplace and clicks "Install" they will get an authorization screen and accept. I should get a code and exchange it for tokens. I would like to test that process before publishing the application. Test Install Flow button should be a way to do that but, as question states, all I see is authorization screen with my requested scope and after I click 'accept' nothing happens. So how do I test getting the code and retrieving tokens?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to your question around the `refresh_token` is - No. You won't get a refresh token upon install. You have to instead ask for a fresh `access_token` using a Service Account key you've got.

So basically, the way a Google Apps Marketplace (GAM) app is supposed to work is to get itself a [Service Account](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount) and [build with that](https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/#serviceaccounts) for all authorization. There are no `refresh_token` with Service Accounts, just fresh new `access_token`. For an app that is installed by consumers you should use standard [web server flow](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer). This is one area of complexity that wants to be both a consumer and enterprise app.

When an admin *installs* your app, he/she is in essence *authorizing* your app's Service Account key to his/her domain.

Once an app is installed, that Service Account has [full delegated access](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation)

Regarding the Install URL for a Drive app. You can ignore that for a GAM app.

Hope this helps. We'll release some end to end sample at some point soon .

Comment: Do you have a suggestion on how developers can test installing an app as an Admin for domain?  Or as a consumer?

Comment: There is a Test Install button available in the Developer Console for the Google Apps Marketplaxe SDK. If you share the project with an admin account of a test domain, then that test account and install/authorize the app. This is the best way to test.