# Google Drive SDK - Drive Integration Install URL

Tags: google-drive-api, google-apps-marketplace

In [Google Console](https://console.developers.google.com/project), Drive SDK integration, there is section for Drive Integration. In there, is a field for Install URL.

[image]

It says: *This URL is used when you want to install this application in Google Drive.* The help button [links to web install help page](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/install).

Question - how exactly is Install URL used? Where in the install process, the Install URL used?

My guess is that user is redirected to install url after authorization. However, I specified this Install URL and when I try testing install flow, nothing happens - [Google Marketplace - Installing application and access tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22226497/installing-google-drive-app-and-access-tokens)

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?

Comment: @dev.e.loper pls share what that install url for, if you've found out what it is