# Google API & Markets : Where and how to publish domain apps?

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

My team is trying to publish our web app in the google market place. The one where domains admins using Google Apps to host their domain will look to add apps to their domain.

Old and new documentation and developer consoles are somehow not clear about where and what to do anymore.

- SSO is working using credentials and tokens provided by the new API dev console
- we managed to go through test setup and apparently went ok
- we want to publish the app on the Google App Marketplace

I suppose : https://www.google.com/enterprise/marketplace/home/apps/?pli=1 is where we want the app to appear through search.

So what the process to follow here ?

thanks in advance

Comment: Curious how did you go about testing Admin installing your Marketplace App? I am assuming that you had to set up a service account that admin's delegate credentials to - http://stackoverflow.com/a/22769252/37759

Answer (score 1):

https://www.google.com/enterprise/marketplace/home/apps/?pli=1 is deprecated.

"There's a new Google Apps Marketplace experience! Beginning November 19, 2013, new listings may only be created using the new version: existing developers may need to create a new Chrome Web Store account to publish new listings. Refer to the new documentation for more information."

New documentation https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/listing